# How to install numpy in pypy2.7-v7.3.9-win64 in windows?

Tags: numpy, python-2.7, pypy

I was trying to install numpy in pypy2.7-v7.3.9-win64 build. I am getting an error while I run **pypy -m pip install numpy** from command prompt.

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: 'C:\Users\user\Downloads\pypy2.7-v7.3.9-win64\pypy2.7.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'c:\\users\\user\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-install-hl94bz\\numpy\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'c:\\users\\user\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-install-hl94bz\\numpy\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pip-record-mrg5fc\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\user\Downloads\pypy2.7-v7.3.9-win64\include\numpy'
     cwd: c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-hl94bz\numpy\
Complete output (306 lines):
Running from numpy source directory.

Note: if you need reliable uninstall behavior, then install
with pip instead of using `setup.py install`:

  - `pip install .`       (from a git repo or downloaded source
                           release)
  - `pip install numpy`   (last NumPy release on PyPi)


blas_opt_info:
blas_mkl_info:
No module named numpy.distutils._msvccompiler in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
customize MSVCCompiler
  libraries mkl_rt not found in ['C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\user\\Downloads\\pypy2.7-v7.3.9-win64\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

blis_info:
No module named numpy.distutils._msvccompiler in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
customize MSVCCompiler
  libraries blis not found in ['C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\user\\Downloads\\pypy2.7-v7.3.9-win64\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

openblas_info:
No module named numpy.distutils._msvccompiler in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
customize MSVCCompiler
No module named numpy.distutils._msvccompiler in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
customize MSVCCompiler
  libraries openblas not found in ['C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\user\\Downloads\\pypy2.7-v7.3.9-win64\\libs']
get_default_fcompiler: matching types: '['gnu', 'intelv', 'absoft', 'compaqv', 'intelev', 'gnu95', 'g95', 'intelvem', 'intelem', 'flang']'
customize GnuFCompiler
Could not locate executable g77
Could not locate executable f77
customize IntelVisualFCompiler
Could not locate executable ifort
Could not locate executable ifl
customize AbsoftFCompiler
Could not locate executable f90
customize CompaqVisualFCompiler
Could not locate executable DF
customize IntelItaniumVisualFCompiler
Could not locate executable efl
customize Gnu95FCompiler
Could not locate executable gfortran
Could not locate executable f95
customize G95FCompiler
Could not locate executable g95
customize IntelEM64VisualFCompiler
customize IntelEM64TFCompiler
Could not locate executable efort
Could not locate executable efc
customize PGroupFlangCompiler
don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'nt'
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:
Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
No module named numpy.distutils._msvccompiler in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
customize MSVCCompiler
  libraries tatlas not found in ['C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\user\\Downloads\\pypy2.7-v7.3.9-win64\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_3_10_blas_info:
No module named numpy.distutils._msvccompiler in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
customize MSVCCompiler
  libraries satlas not found in ['C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\user\\Downloads\\pypy2.7-v7.3.9-win64\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_blas_threads_info:
Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
No module named numpy.distutils._msvccompiler in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
customize MSVCCompiler
  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\user\\Downloads\\pypy2.7-v7.3.9-win64\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_blas_info:
No module named numpy.distutils._msvccompiler in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
customize MSVCCompiler
  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\user\\Downloads\\pypy2.7-v7.3.9-win64\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

accelerate_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE

c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-hl94bz\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:639: UserWarning:
    Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
    the ATLAS environment variable.
  self.calc_info()
blas_info:
No module named numpy.distutils._msvccompiler in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
customize MSVCCompiler
  libraries blas not found in ['C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\user\\Downloads\\pypy2.7-v7.3.9-win64\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-hl94bz\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:639: UserWarning:
    Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
    the BLAS environment variable.
  self.calc_info()
blas_src_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE

c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-hl94bz\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:639: UserWarning:
    Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
    Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
    the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
  self.calc_info()
  NOT AVAILABLE

non-existing path in 'numpy\\distutils': 'site.cfg'
lapack_opt_info:
lapack_mkl_info:
No module named numpy.distutils._msvccompiler in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
customize MSVCCompiler
  libraries mkl_rt not found in ['C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\user\\Downloads\\pypy2.7-v7.3.9-win64\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

openblas_lapack_info:
No module named numpy.distutils._msvccompiler in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
customize MSVCCompiler
No module named numpy.distutils._msvccompiler in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
customize MSVCCompiler
  libraries openblas not found in ['C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\user\\Downloads\\pypy2.7-v7.3.9-win64\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

openblas_clapack_info:
No module named numpy.distutils._msvccompiler in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
customize MSVCCompiler
No module named numpy.distutils._msvccompiler in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
customize MSVCCompiler
  libraries openblas,lapack not found in ['C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\user\\Downloads\\pypy2.7-v7.3.9-win64\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_3_10_threads_info:
Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
No module named numpy.distutils._msvccompiler in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
customize MSVCCompiler
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
No module named numpy.distutils._msvccompiler in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
customize MSVCCompiler
  libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\
No module named numpy.distutils._msvccompiler in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
customize MSVCCompiler
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\user\Downloads\pypy2.7-v7.3.9-win64\libs
No module named numpy.distutils._msvccompiler in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
customize MSVCCompiler
  libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\Users\user\Downloads\pypy2.7-v7.3.9-win64\libs
<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_3_10_info:
No module named numpy.distutils._msvccompiler in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
customize MSVCCompiler
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
No module named numpy.distutils._msvccompiler in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
customize MSVCCompiler
  libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\
No module named numpy.distutils._msvccompiler in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
customize MSVCCompiler
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\user\Downloads\pypy2.7-v7.3.9-win64\libs
No module named numpy.distutils._msvccompiler in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
customize MSVCCompiler
  libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\Users\user\Downloads\pypy2.7-v7.3.9-win64\libs
<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_threads_info:
Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
No module named numpy.distutils._msvccompiler in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
customize MSVCCompiler
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
No module named numpy.distutils._msvccompiler in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
customize MSVCCompiler
  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\
No module named numpy.distutils._msvccompiler in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
customize MSVCCompiler
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\user\Downloads\pypy2.7-v7.3.9-win64\libs
No module named numpy.distutils._msvccompiler in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
customize MSVCCompiler
  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\user\Downloads\pypy2.7-v7.3.9-win64\libs
<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_info:
No module named numpy.distutils._msvccompiler in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
customize MSVCCompiler
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
No module named numpy.distutils._msvccompiler in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
customize MSVCCompiler
  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\
No module named numpy.distutils._msvccompiler in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
customize MSVCCompiler
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\user\Downloads\pypy2.7-v7.3.9-win64\libs
No module named numpy.distutils._msvccompiler in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
customize MSVCCompiler
  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\user\Downloads\pypy2.7-v7.3.9-win64\libs
<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
  NOT AVAILABLE

lapack_info:
No module named numpy.distutils._msvccompiler in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
customize MSVCCompiler
  libraries lapack not found in ['C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\user\\Downloads\\pypy2.7-v7.3.9-win64\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-hl94bz\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:639: UserWarning:
    Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
    the LAPACK environment variable.
  self.calc_info()
lapack_src_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE

c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-hl94bz\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:639: UserWarning:
    Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
    Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
    the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
  self.calc_info()
  NOT AVAILABLE

C:\Users\user\Downloads\pypy2.7-v7.3.9-win64\lib-python\2.7\distutils\dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
  warnings.warn(msg)
running install
running build
running config_cc
unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
running config_fc
unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
running build_src
build_src
building py_modules sources
creating build
creating build\src.win-amd64-2.7
creating build\src.win-amd64-2.7\numpy
creating build\src.win-amd64-2.7\numpy\distutils
building library "npymath" sources
No module named numpy.distutils._msvccompiler in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<module>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-hl94bz\numpy\setup.py", line 419, in <module>
    setup_package()
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-hl94bz\numpy\setup.py", line 411, in setup_package
    setup(**metadata)
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-hl94bz\numpy\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 171, in setup
    return old_setup(**new_attr)
  File "C:\Users\user\Downloads\pypy2.7-v7.3.9-win64\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 145, in setup
    return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "C:\Users\user\Downloads\pypy2.7-v7.3.9-win64\lib-python\2.7\distutils\core.py", line 151, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Users\user\Downloads\pypy2.7-v7.3.9-win64\lib-python\2.7\distutils\dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Users\user\Downloads\pypy2.7-v7.3.9-win64\lib-python\2.7\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-hl94bz\numpy\numpy\distutils\command\install.py", line 62, in run
    r = self.setuptools_run()
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-hl94bz\numpy\numpy\distutils\command\install.py", line 36, in setuptools_run
    return distutils_install.run(self)
  File "C:\Users\user\Downloads\pypy2.7-v7.3.9-win64\lib-python\2.7\distutils\command\install.py", line 588, in run
    self.run_command('build')
  File "C:\Users\user\Downloads\pypy2.7-v7.3.9-win64\lib-python\2.7\distutils\cmd.py", line 334, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\Users\user\Downloads\pypy2.7-v7.3.9-win64\lib-python\2.7\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-hl94bz\numpy\numpy\distutils\command\build.py", line 47, in run
    old_build.run(self)
  File "C:\Users\user\Downloads\pypy2.7-v7.3.9-win64\lib-python\2.7\distutils\command\build.py", line 127, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "C:\Users\user\Downloads\pypy2.7-v7.3.9-win64\lib-python\2.7\distutils\cmd.py", line 334, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\Users\user\Downloads\pypy2.7-v7.3.9-win64\lib-python\2.7\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-hl94bz\numpy\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 148, in run
    self.build_sources()
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-hl94bz\numpy\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 159, in build_sources
    self.build_library_sources(*libname_info)
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-hl94bz\numpy\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 292, in build_library_sources
    sources = self.generate_sources(sources, (lib_name, build_info))
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-hl94bz\numpy\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 375, in generate_sources
    source = func(extension, build_dir)
  File "numpy\core\setup.py", line 665, in get_mathlib_info
    st = config_cmd.try_link('int main(void) { return 0;}')
  File "C:\Users\user\Downloads\pypy2.7-v7.3.9-win64\lib-python\2.7\distutils\command\config.py", line 251, in try_link
    libraries, library_dirs, lang)
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-hl94bz\numpy\numpy\distutils\command\config.py", line 164, in _link
    libraries, library_dirs, lang))
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-hl94bz\numpy\numpy\distutils\command\config.py", line 96, in _wrap_method
    ret = mth(*((self,)+args))
  File "C:\Users\user\Downloads\pypy2.7-v7.3.9-win64\lib-python\2.7\distutils\command\config.py", line 143, in _link
    (src, obj) = self._compile(body, headers, include_dirs, lang)
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-hl94bz\numpy\numpy\distutils\command\config.py", line 106, in _compile
    (body, headers, include_dirs, lang))
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-hl94bz\numpy\numpy\distutils\command\config.py", line 96, in _wrap_method
    ret = mth(*((self,)+args))
  File "C:\Users\user\Downloads\pypy2.7-v7.3.9-win64\lib-python\2.7\distutils\command\config.py", line 138, in _compile
    self.compiler.compile([src], include_dirs=include_dirs)
  File "C:\Users\user\Downloads\pypy2.7-v7.3.9-win64\lib-python\2.7\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 401, in compile
    self.spawn(args)
  File "C:\Users\user\Downloads\pypy2.7-v7.3.9-win64\lib-python\2.7\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 505, in spawn
    return CCompiler.spawn(self, cmd, env=env)
TypeError: CCompiler_spawn() got an unexpected keyword argument 'env'
----------------------------------------
```

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\user\Downloads\pypy2.7-v7.3.9-win64\pypy2.7.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-hl94bz\numpy\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-hl94bz\numpy\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pip-record-mrg5fc\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\user\Downloads\pypy2.7-v7.3.9-win64\include\numpy' Check the logs for full command output.

Is it possible to install numpy in pypy with python2.7 ? Please help us..

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you must use a NumPy that is compatible with Python2.7. The last version of NumPy that support Python2.7 is [v1.16.6](https://pypi.org/project/numpy/1.16.6/#files)

Comment: Still stuck with same error while installing numpy.